# Cannot get stdoutput from freeGlut project

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipe, freeglut

I have free glut project with code that calculates voronoy mesh, initializes freeglut and then draws mesh.

```
pre-calculations
...
printf("Elapsed %lf seconds\n", (double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
glutInit            ( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
glutInitWindowSize  ( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

// create window
glutCreateWindow ( "Voronoy" );

// register handlers
glutDisplayFunc  ( display );
glutReshapeFunc  ( reshape );
glutKeyboardFunc ( key     );


glutMainLoop ();


return 0;
...
```

So the program works in console mode and then creates freeglut window.
And also I have separate program which reads from stdout pipe connected to this. I create process with this parameters

```
STARTUPINFO        si;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));

si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdInput = stdinput.ReadPipe();
si.hStdOutput = stdoutput.WritePipe();
si.hStdError = stderror.WritePipe();
stdoutput.DuplicateReadPipe();

if ( !CreateProcess( "j:\\Projects\\study\\fortune\\Debug\\voronoy.exe",//"C:\\GnuWin32\\bin\\ls.exe",
    NULL,
    NULL, NULL,
    TRUE,
    (CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM | CREATE_NO_WINDOW),
    NULL, NULL,
    &si, &process_info) )
{
    throw("!!!");
}
DWORD w = ResumeThread(process_info.hThread);
CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
```

And I've also tried standard Pipes example from MSDN.

The problem is that program recives no data from pipe.
I've also tried voronoy.exe > test.txt in cmd.exe and test.txt remains empty.
But if I run it without pipes - it works fine and I can see output in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. I need to flush std output by simply calling

```
fflush(stdout);
```